# Подскажите как адаптировать под мобильную версию?

Tags: css, mobile

Сразу скажу, я пробовал ставить проценты и убирать position:absolute, но не получилось... Код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#timer").countdown({
    since: new Date(2015, 8, 6, 00, 00, 00),
    http: //ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
      format: "YODHMS",
    layout: '<dl><dt id="years_lbl">YEARS</dt><dd id="years">{ynn}</dd><dt id="months_lbl">MONTHS</dt><dd id="months">{onn}</dd><dt id="days_lbl">DAYS</dt><dd id="days">{dnn}</dd><dt id="hrs_lbl">HOURS</dt><dd id="hours">{hnn}</dd><dt id="mins_lbl">MINUTES</dt><dd id="minutes">{mnn}</dd><dt id="secs_lbl">SECONDS</dt><dd id="seconds">{snn}</dd></dl>'
  });
});
```

```css
dl {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px auto 50px;
  width: 810px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
}
dt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 135px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
dd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 135px;
}
dt#years_lbl,
dd#years {
  left: 0;
}
dt#months_lbl,
dd#months {
  left: 135px;
}
dd#days {
  left: 270px;
}
dd#hours {
  left: 405px;
}
dt#mins_lbl,
dd#minutes {
  left: 540px;
}
dt#secs_lbl,
dd#seconds {
  left: 675px;
}
#dl * {
  text-outline: 1px 1px #000;
}
dt#days_lbl {
  left: 290px;
}
dt#hrs_lbl {
  left: 415px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<article class="article-timer">
  <center>
    <div style="font-family:verdana; " id="timer"></div>
  </center>
</article>
<article class="article-timer">
  <center>
    <div style="font-family:verdana; " id="timer"></div>
  </center>
</article>
```

Comment: у меня не получается отредактировать CSS...извините...

Answer (score 1):

Одно из самых важных, что должно быть в коде внутри тега **`<head>`** так это мета которая говорит браузеру что сайт должен еще и отображаться корректно на мобильных устройствах **`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes"/>`** к примеру вот так. А в **css** стоит еще применить **@media () {};** на проверку ширины экрана.

Второе чтобы я еще посоветовал использовать [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) что упростит Вам в целом писать css-разметки и классы для мобильных устройств

P.S. Я не пойму кто учит людей использовать в CSS и в верстке привязку к ID стилей, єто очень плохой тон, мало того **ID всегда должен быть уникален** и Ваш код вырастит как гриб при хороших условиях, а в итоге того, что Вам явно говорили, что так типа быстрее будет работать и учитывая объем содержимого css (размер файла и кол-во строк), да и сама скорость обработки не на много быстрее, если вы будите привязывать стиль через class... короче только хуже сделаете. Не нужно использовать ID для подвязки стиля элементу Вы только себе так жизнь усложняете.

```
$(function() {
  $(".timer").countdown({
    since: new Date(2015, 8, 6, 00, 00, 00),
      format: "YODHMS",
    layout: '<dl><dt class="years_lbl">YEARS</dt><dd class="years">{ynn}</dd><dt class="months_lbl">MONTHS</dt><dd class="months">{onn}</dd><dt class="days_lbl">DAYS</dt><dd class="days">{dnn}</dd><dt class="hrs_lbl">HOURS</dt><dd class="hours">{hnn}</dd><dt class="mins_lbl">MINUTES</dt><dd class="minutes">{mnn}</dd><dt class="secs_lbl">SECONDS</dt><dd class="seconds">{snn}</dd></dl>'
  });
});

.timer {
  font-family:verdana;
}

<article class="article-timer">
  <center>
    <div class="timer"></div>
  </center>
</article>
<article class="article-timer">
  <center>
    <div class="timer"></div>
  </center>
</article>
```

Comment: Сайт на вордпрессе. Сам сайт адаптивный, но этот кусок я  добавил сам. Я не знаю как делать с media queries. Можете написать? Я говорю, пробовал процентами - не работает

Comment: Можете подсказать? Не получается ..